# Matplotlib colorbar when LogNorm and ImageGrid is used

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been trying to plot some panels using `ImageGrid`. When I use `grid.cbar_axes[0].colorbar(im)` to set the colorbar the colors look fine, but the scale on the colorbar reads like it's going from `2x10^0` to `None`.

I have tried dozens of workarounds but nothing worked. Here's the figure I'm trying to make (my wrong version):

[image]

Unfortunately I couldn't make a MWE that perfectly reproduces the problem. I did produce a MWE that partially reproduces it. If I use this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

def get_demo_image():
    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib.cbook import get_sample_data
    f = get_sample_data("axes_grid/bivariate_normal.npy", asfileobj=False)
    z = np.load(f)
    return abs(z), (-3, 4, -4, 3)

F = plt.figure(figsize=(5.5, 3.5))
grid = ImageGrid(F, 111,  # similar to subplot(111)
                 nrows_ncols=(1, 3),
                 axes_pad=0.1,
                 add_all=True,
                 label_mode="L",
                 cbar_mode='single'
                 )

Z, extent = get_demo_image()  # demo image

im1 = Z
im2 = Z
im3 = Z
vmin, vmax = 1e-3, 1e10
for i, im in enumerate([im1, im2, im3]):
    ax = grid[i]
    imc = ax.pcolormesh(range(15), range(15), im, norm=LogNorm(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax), linewidth=0, rasterized=True)

cb=grid.cbar_axes[0].colorbar(imc)
```

[image]

I get almost the same behavior, except that the upper limit appears to be fine. The lower limit still presents the same weird behavior, no matter what values I use for `vmin` and `vmax`.

Any idea of what might be going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the [official example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_axes_grid2.html) uses something similar to 
`cb=grid.cbar_axes[0].colorbar(imc)`, which would translate here into `grid[2].cax.colorbar(im)`, I'm lost on why that would even make sense.

Instead, the usual way to produce a colorbar would also work here, using the colorbar method of `Figure` with the ScalarMappable (here `imc`) as argument
and the axes to produce the colorbar as keywordargument to `cax` (here `grid[2].cax`):

```
cb=F.colorbar(imc, cax=grid[2].cax)
```

[image]

Comment: I found other odd results when using the official example for the `colorbar` of `ImageGrid`. Using instead the method of `Figure` as suggested here solves the problems.